# How to Embed multiple tweets of various users into HTML in django framework?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, tweepy

I am passing a data in the form of a dictionary from views.py to results.html in Django framework. The dictionary has the following format

'tweet': (tweet_analysis, tweet_id)

now in results.html, called by the views.py, 
I am trying to Embed all the tweets that are passed to results.html, but the following code only displays one embedded tweet.

dicPositive: This is the dictionary containing all the tweets data

```
    {% for tweet, tweet_feel in dicPositive.items %}

        <div id="tweet" tweetID="{{tweet_feel.1}}"></div>

            <script sync src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

            <script>
              window.onload = (function(){

                var tweet = document.getElementById("tweet");
                var id = tweet.getAttribute("tweetID");

                twttr.widgets.createTweet(
                  id, tweet,
                  {
                    conversation : 'none',    // or all
                    cards        : 'hidden',  // or visible
                    linkColor    : '#cc0000', // default is blue
                    theme        : 'light'    // or dark
                  })
                .then (function (el) {
                  el.contentDocument.querySelector(".footer").style.display = "none";
                });

              });
            </script>

        <!-- <li>{{tweet}} &ndash;&gt;  {{tweet_feel.0}}  &ndash;&gt; {{tweet_feel.1}}</li> -->
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: check my answer, is that worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have used same `id` for multiple HTMLElements created while looping.

> You must add loop counter to **`id` attribute of `div`** and also when
>   you are fetching it using **`getElementById`** inside `script` tag

```
{% for tweet, tweet_feel in dicPositive.items %}

    <div id="tweet_{{forloop.counter}}" tweetID="{{tweet_feel.1}}"></div>

    <script sync src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    <script>
       window.onload = (function(){
           var tweet = document.getElementById("tweet_{{forloop.counter}}");

           # Rest of your code
           ...

    </script>

{% endfor %}
```